# Linux remove all *.sln file exclude one file

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci.yml

Can I know how to remove all *.sln file but exclude "work.sln" in the same folder
I try run `rm *.sln !("work.sln")`
it return `/bin/bash: eval: line 128: syntax error near unexpected token` ('`

Thank you

Comment: The immediate problem is that you seem to have forgotten `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are already inside the folder that contains the files you need, this is one way to do it (also assuming you are looking for a one-line version, given your example)

```
for file in $(ls);do if [[ ! $file == work.sln ]]; then rm $file; fi; done
```

EDIT: as @tripleee pointed out, the `ls` can be avoided and re-written like this

```
for file in *; do if [[ ! $file == work.sln ]]; then rm $file; fi; done
```

Comment: That's a [useless `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls); you want simply `for file in *` (or for robustness `for file in ./*` but then you have to update the rest of the code to include the `./` everywhere).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it could be written like that